Get ARN of the latest version AWS managed Pandas layer
Is it possible to get ARN of the latest version of AWS managed pandas layer AWSSDKPandas for python 3.11 via aws command?

TL;DR: no
aws lambda list-layers & aws lambda list-layer-versions only list layers owned by your AWS account.
Invoking aws lambda list-layer-versions with the option --query  LayerVersions[0].LayerVersionArn should allow you to see the latest version of a layer if you know the name or ARN, but I suppose ListLayerVersions is not allowed to be performed on AWS managed layers
